# Many "Includes" on Entity Framework Core with MySql Provider

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm trying to consult database with query like this:

```
var query = _context.Transactions
    .Include(x => x.TransactionStatus)
    .Include(x => x.Department)
    .Include(x => x.Group)
    .Include(x => x.Signatories)
    .Include(x => x.Provider)
    .Where(x => x.GroupId == request.GroupId);
```

This query works correctly with Azure SQL, but with MySql does not return records.

I'm using Pomelo and my tables are InnoDB.

Any idea?

Comment: well are there any records in the table?

Comment: @MUG4N Yes! I have filled my database. Azure SQL and MySQL are identical...